# print to the end of terminal

Tags: bash, terminal

Like this picture of apt-get, how can I print something at the end of the line, just like the speed on the screen. Although I can use escape like `\e[C` to make it move several columns to the right and print, but the speed varies and the string length varies. Can anyone tell me how to do this? I am currently programming using bash. Thanks.[image: apt-get]

Comment: Does it help to your question?
[How to add a progress bar to a shell script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238073/how-to-add-a-progress-bar-to-a-shell-script)

Comment: Well, actually I've thought of that, but it is kind of trouble to do it manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often you will find the width of the console window in the environment variable [`COLUMNS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-COLUMNS), but this is not completely reliable. A more reliable solution is to use the `tput` utility (part of ncurses, but can be used standalone) with the argument `cols`:

```
$ echo $COLUMNS
148
$ tput cols
148
```

A simple way to split text is to use the Posix-standard `printf` utility to first print the text to be aligned on the right margin padded to the column width, then output a carriage return (`\r`) to return the cursor to the beginning of the line, and then print the text to be aligned on the left margin. Finally a newline will move to the next line. Or, in code:

```
# Call it like this:
# print_both_sides "This goes on the left" "and this goes on the right."
print_both_sides() {
  printf "\r%*s\r%s\n" $(tput cols) "$2" "$1";
}
```

The `printf` format uses the standard feature of `*` replacements for field width and precision format modifiers; the `*` means that the corresponding number should be taken from an argument. In this case, I use `$(tput cols)` -- i.e. the width of the console window -- as the first argument for the format code `%*s`, which has the effect of right-padding the next string argument (`"$2"`) in a field whose width is precisely the width of the console.

I added an additional carriage return to the beginning of the output in case the cursor is currently not at the left margin.

Comment: The `*` means that the field width should be read from an argument. Other than that, it's a normal `%s` with a field width. Eg., `%80s` would right-pad the string argument in a field of 80 spaces. In this case, I use `$(tput cols)` as the field width argument, which will be the width of the console window.

Comment: That's good. Is there a way to do it using `echo` instead of `printf`?

Comment: @Chromium: why would you care? `printf` is posix standard and a bash built-in. Posix recommends that you use `printf` instead of `echo`.

Comment: Oh, really. BUT I still care about that because almost every `stdout` in my program uses `echo`.

Comment: The lead sentence is incorrect: `COLUMNS` *may* contain value, but that is more of an exception than a general rule, and usually regarded as a nuisance.

Comment: @ThomasDickey: It should have the correct value if you're using `bash`, but I agree that it is not reliable which is why I didn't use it in the later examples. I changed the lede to note the unreliability of COLUMNS, although it might not be a strongly-worded as you would have written it.

Answer (score 1):

In a terminal, there is more than one way to obtain the actual screen-width:

- if the terminal/connection can successfully negotiate the screen size, that (usually) results in a correct value shown in `stty -a` (the `columns` value usually on the first line of the report).
- the command-line [`tput`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html) utility consults this information, overriding any *constant* value for the number of columns from the terminal database, and can print it, e.g, `tput cols`.
- the environment variables `LINES` and `COLUMNS` *usually* override that in full-screen applications (including those using curses: see [`use_env`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_util.3x.html#h3-use_env)).
- sometimes the information is just wrong (see the xterm FAQ [Why is my screensize not set?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#setup_resize)).  For terminals supporting the [VT100-style](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) cursor-position report (also in [ECMA-48](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm), *8.3.14 CPR - ACTIVE POSITION REPORT*), you can use [`resize`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/resize.html) to update the `stty` setting and optionally update `LINES` and `COLUMNS`.

When printing using escape sequences, there are a few different ways to *use* this information about the screen-width, which are widely supported.  The command-line `tput` utility also can retrieve these from the terminal description (which may lack specific features):

- absolute cursor positioning, allows you to move the cursor to a specific *row* and *column* on the screen: `tput cup $row $column`
- horizontal cursor positioning, allows you to move the cursor to a specific column on the current row: `tput hpa $column`
- relative cursor positioning, allows you to move the cursor left or right (or up or down), a given number of cells, e.g., `tput cuf $value` to move forward (to the right) by the given number of cells.  Regarding the question, using a parameter like this is usually faster than repeating single movements as done with `tput`**`cuf1`**.

The capabilities `cup`, `hpa`, `cuf` correspond generally to names in ECMA-48 and are described in the [terminfo(5)](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html) manual page.

To print text at the right-side of the screen, you would do this:

- obtain the number of columns in the screen,
- determine the number of columns which your text will use,
- compute the starting column: right-margin minus the number of columns in the text
- move the cursor to the starting column
- print the text, e.g., using `echo` or `printf`.  The latter has more flexibility.

If you use the command-line [`printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) utility, you may keep in mind that handling multibyte characters such as UTF-8 is not well-supported when you want to know the *width* of a given string, so portability may be a concern.

Further reading:

- [printf field width doesn't support multibyte characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885811/printf-field-width-doesnt-support-multibyte-characters)
- [UTF-8 Width Display Issue of Chinese Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751867/utf-8-width-display-issue-of-chinese-characters)