# Shell: printf alignment is inconsistent for non-ASCII text

Tags: shell, printf

I'm writing a makefile that creates directories and displays a special message if the newly created dir is empty. This is done with a macro:

```
CREADIRVACIO = @printf "Creando directorio %-50s ¡DIRECTORIO VACÍO!\n"
```

With this macro, I call the message with its appropirate dir name and it's printed:

```
$(CREADIRVACIO) "Fundamentos de programación"
@mkdir $(FP_OUT)
```

My problem here is that the output part that says `¡DIRECTORIO VACÍO!` should be aligned in the same column. It's not:

```
➜ make
==========================
# COMENZANDO COMPILACIÓN #
==========================

Eliminando compilación anterior
Creando raíz de archivos compilados

Creando directorio 1º 1er cuatrimestre
Creando directorio Álgebra lineal y estructuras matemáticas         ¡DIRECTORIO VACÍO!
Creando directorio Cálculo                                           ¡DIRECTORIO VACÍO!
Creando directorio Fundamentos físicos y tecnológicos               ¡DIRECTORIO VACÍO!
Creando directorio Fundamentos de programación                       ¡DIRECTORIO VACÍO!
Creando directorio Fundamentos del software                           ¡DIRECTORIO VACÍO!
Creando directorio 1º 2º cuatrimestre
Creando directorio Estadística                                       ¡DIRECTORIO VACÍO!
Creando directorio Ingeniería, empresa y sociedad                    ¡DIRECTORIO VACÍO!
Creando directorio Lógica y métodos discretos                       ¡DIRECTORIO VACÍO!
Creando directorio Metodología de la programación                   ¡DIRECTORIO VACÍO!
Creando directorio Tecnología y organización de los computadores    ¡DIRECTORIO VACÍO!
Creando directorio 2º 1er cuatrimestre
Creando directorio Estructura de computadores                         ¡DIRECTORIO VACÍO!
Creando directorio Estructura de datos                                ¡DIRECTORIO VACÍO!
Creando directorio Programación y diseño orientado a objetos        ¡DIRECTORIO VACÍO!
Creando directorio Sistemas concurrentes y distribuidos               ¡DIRECTORIO VACÍO!
Creando directorio Sistemas operativos                                ¡DIRECTORIO VACÍO!
Creando directorio 2º 2º cuatrimestre
Creando directorio Arquitectura de computadores                       ¡DIRECTORIO VACÍO!
Creando directorio Algorítmica                                       ¡DIRECTORIO VACÍO!
Creando directorio Fundamentos de bases de datos                      ¡DIRECTORIO VACÍO!
Creando directorio Fundamentos de ingeniería del software            ¡DIRECTORIO VACÍO!
Creando directorio Inteligencia artificial                            ¡DIRECTORIO VACÍO!
Creando directorio 3º 1er cuatrimestre
Creando directorio Diseño y desarrollo de sistemas de información   ¡DIRECTORIO VACÍO!
Creando directorio Fundamentos de redes                               ¡DIRECTORIO VACÍO!
Creando directorio Informática gráfica                              ¡DIRECTORIO VACÍO!
Creando directorio Ingeniería de servidores                          ¡DIRECTORIO VACÍO!
Creando directorio Modelos de computación                            ¡DIRECTORIO VACÍO!
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: This is more of a bash/shell question, as it's not make that is causing the behavior.   (note -- your issue is related to the multi-byte accent characters you are using)

Comment: Here `printf` counts bytes, not chars, so alignment is wrong.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6885918/8710344 for a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks @hardcoreHenry, the `awk` solution worked!